# What archive and compression tool can handle parts most comfortably without using cat?

Tags: command-line, tar, compression, tools

I have a folder with lots of files of different formats and sizes. The whole folder contains other folders and everything sums up in size to 16G. I'm looking for a Linux tool to achieve the following goals:

- Reduce overall file size (to save space)
- Splitting it in multiple parts (for easily sending it over a network)
- Listing of containing files without using a 'cat' command beforehand (to save time and space)
- Extracting a single or multiple file(s) without to untar the whole archive and without using 'cat' (to make it comfortable to use)
- Extracting a group of files or folders
- Stability

Bonus, but *optional*:

- using all available CPU cores to speed up the process

Does such a tool exist in the Linux world?

Comment: I've never seen someone use `cat` for archives. `cat` is mostly useful to display text files. What exactly do you mean? Listing the contents of an archive does not require "space", any archiving tool just needs to read the index of the archive, it doesn't have to be decompressed.

Comment: Let's say you split a huge tar.xz etc into parts using `split` tool you have to use `cat` to merge the parts together again. Only then you can list files and extract single files etc. I'm looking for a way to avoid `cat` and find a compression tool that is able to handle listing, extracting files/folders over a multi part archive on its own without concatenation the parts first.

Comment: I see. I didn't understand because I've usually used archiving formats that support splitting, e.g. 7z. With a multi-part 7z file you can use `lsar` and `unar` without joining the pieces. It doesn't work with `split` chunks unfortunately.

Comment: One idea would be to split your large directory tree into several smaller ones first, either manually or [automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10158/splitting-large-directory-tree-into-specified-size-chunks), and then compress those individually, so that you don't have to uncompress all of it to get one file. Should not be too hard to automate this with a shell script - i don't know how though. I've read that [backup2l](http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/) can do this.

Comment: I did `tar cf - directory | 7za a -si -v480m directory.tar.7z` and got 33 parts. But how can I see what's inside those files or extract something from it? I tried `lsar` for listing files but that seems to only work when the parts are concatenated to one file. :/